# @Async en Spring boot no funciona de forma paralela

Tags: spring, async

quiero realizar una conexión ssh varias veces de forma simultanea para disminuir el tiempo de ejecución de las tareas pero al utilizar el @Async solo me ejecuta un hilo
tengo esto  donde desde el controller recorro un array con los datos de los host y ejecuto la conexión de forma paralela con el Async

```
@SpringBootApplication

@EnableAsync
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean(name="rulesThreadExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Rules-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

}
```

Comment: En el Servicio tengo lo siguiente:
     
        @Async ("rulesThreadExecutor")
     public CompletableFuture<String> QueryWwn3 (String Ip, String Pwd, String User, String command, String HostName) {
      
       List<String> OutConnect=new ArrayList<String>();
       OutConnect=NuevoSsh.conection(Ip, Pwd, User, command); 
       System.out.println(OutConnect.get(0));
      return(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(OutConnect.get(0)));
      
     
     }

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error es definir `setCorePoolSize` como 1. En mi caso, tengo configurado el Executor de la siguiente forma:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    ...

    return executor;

}
```

Te recomiendo que en caso de añadir nueva información, edites tu pregunta en lugar de añadir un comentario.